# Syntax error in a correct query while creating a view in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a view from the following query:

```
SELECT 
    `Logs`.`ID`,
    `Logs`.`Date`,
    `Logs`.`Full log`,
    `Logs`.`Medium log`,
    `Logs`.`Minimal log`,
    `Machines`.`Name` AS `Machine name`
FROM 
    `Logs`
LEFT JOIN
    `Machines`
ON
    `Logs`.`Machine ID` = `Machines`.`ID`;
```

It works when executed in MySQL, but for some reason phpmyadmin doesn't allow me to create a view based on that query. I get the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS SELECT 
    `Logs`.`ID`,
    `Logs`.`Date`,
    `Logs`.`Full log`,
    `Logs' at line 4
```

I have no idea why that error occurs because the query is correct.

Comment: Can you show us the code you used to execute `CREATE VIEW` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I used the "Create view" option in the "Query results operations" section in phpmyadmin. It doesn't show the query which it uses to create the view.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that phpmyadmin doesn't provide a default value for the view name if the "VIEW name" field is empty in the view configuration dialog. All I had to do was to enter the name of the view. In my opinion they should make that field mandatory.

Comment: Good on you for answering your own question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was in a hurry and I asked the question without doing the proper research for which I'm sorry. Shortly after asking the question I found the solution. I didn't want to waste your time so I just posted it as an answer to this question.

Comment: I created an issue to track this improvement: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12394

Comment: This has been fixed in phpMyAdmin and will be part of the next release (4.6.4) which is expected within the next few weeks.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch Awesome, thanks for informing them about this issue.